# FTP connector in Azure fails

Tags: azure, ftp, ftp-client, azure-logic-apps

We try to set up a FTP connection in `Azure`, to use in a Logic App. Seems very straightforward, the instructions are very clear:
https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connector-ftp/

When we click on 'create' (of the `FTP Connector`, so before we are actually in the logic app), absolutely nothing happens. The button turns grey, but nothing happens. No notifications, no fails, no FTP connector.
When we try to set up the FTP connector directly in logic app, we get the error message 'error fetching the deployment template. please try again'.

We have tested the connection in `FileZilla`, this works. We have tested with 2 different FTP connections, both same result. We have played with every parameter in the settings, no change.

We searched here on Stack Overflow, but we haven't found anything that helps. Most questions related to FTP connections and Azure describe situations where it is necessary to connect to Azure. In this case, Azure would be the client and we want to pull in data from a third party's FTP server to analyze in a HDInsight cluster.

We'd like to fix this issue, but it's very difficult with no error message and no response. Has anyone else experienced this and how did you fix it? Does anyone have a clue how to further debug?
Thank you for your time and effort - I'm aware there is not a lot of information here, which is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same steps as mentions in link. It created **FTP connector**  successfully. Use portal for this https://portal.azure.com. What service plan you are using? I am using pay-as-go service plan where it's allow to create me.

Comment: This was actually quite helpful - we were working on a plan from the microsoft partner network.  Switching to another plan helped and enabled us to make the FTP connection.

So this is a nice workaround, thank you very much!

That having said, original problem is not resolved, I want to be able to create the connector in the original plan as well.

Comment: Now r u able to create ftp connector?